# How to apply a css class to all <TD> elements between two clicks on a html page?

Tags: jquery, css

I am implementing a planner web application. Basically, the user clicks on two dates and all dates between the two clicks will be selected.

This should look as follows:
User clicks on day 5:
[image: User clicks on day 5]

Then he clicks on day 7:
[image]

And day 6 is magically selected as well.

The example above is simple in that three days from the same week are selected. But it must be possible to select multiple days across a weekend as well.

First selection (before the weekend):
[image]

Second selection (after the weekend, user selected day 12):
[image]

Days 9 and 10 are weekend days, so they will not be selected. The problem is here: how to define the query to get `<td>` elements in rows of the table above the clicked element?

Thusfar  I have come up with the following jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("td.elegible").click(function () {
        $(this).children().filter("#event").toggleClass("event");
    });
});
```

The element being queried is:

```html
<tr>
  <td class="elegible">
   <span class="number">@day.Date.Day</span>
   <span id="event"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

This code will toggle the appearance of the green bar (indicating selection) and using this I can get days 5,6 and 7 selected too by clicking all three days. But how can I accomplish that when I just click day 5 and day 7 day 6 is selected as well? Moreover: how do I prevent all days before day 5 becoming selected when no other days have been selected before this?

I tried several traversal functions (parent(),children(), find(), filter(), you name it) but I have been unable to get this working. Any nudge in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What framework are you using? Or is it simply Html?

Comment: *"Any nudge in the right direction"* - `.prevUntil()`

Comment: @JamesS It is a razor page.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes I am trying it with `prevUntil()`, but that will add the `event` class to all elements before day 5 when I select that.

Comment: @freedomn-m and `prevUntil`seems only to work for `<td>` elements within the same `<tr>` element, I cannot get it to work on previous rows on the `<table>`

Comment: Keep a reference to the day number in the HTML. On click, record the 2 clicked days based on the HTML element clicked, do the maths, apply to what is needed.

Comment: You really haven't provided enough information.  Nowhere in your question are multiple tr rows even implied.  You would use prevUntil *with* `.event` - that's the "until" part.  But no it won't work on mutliple TRs or multiple pages (which also isn't mentioned - maybe you have multiple pages, maybe you don't, it's not mentioned, neither was TRs.   The correct way to do this would be server side or with data, not via HTML.

Comment: @freedomn-m I added more examples. I would prefer not sending anything to the server before the user has confirmed that the selected days indeed are the days he intended to select.

Comment: What happens if user selects 12 first, then 7?

Comment: @MrUpsidown preferably that would make no difference, but I will be perfectly happy with a solution that will require the first selection to be 7.

Comment: Not entirely relevant to the question, but IDs must be unique: `.filter("#event")` implies there are multiple spans with the same id.  Use classes or data- attributes.

Comment: You store the selection outside of the HTML - eg in an array.  Then, on the second click, you determine, in js, which days are between the two dates and apply it to the table/HTML - rather than change HTML then apply to the data.

Comment: @MrUpsidown good for you, what's your point?  It's also "the same" as my earlier comment, but clarified / expanded on "with data".  And my earlier comment was made at the same time as your comment (middle of typing mine when you finished yours).

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in a comment, it would be quite easy to achieve if you keep track of the day number in the HTML (as a data attribute for example).

Below is a simple example. It allows selecting only 1 date, and dates in reverse order.

```js
$(function() {

  var d1, d2; // Days
  var selectStarted = false; // Flag

  $('.day').on('click', function() {

    if (selectStarted === false) {

      // Select first day
      d1 = $(this).data('day');

      // Set flag
      selectStarted = true;

    } else {

      // Select second day
      d2 = $(this).data('day');

      var diff = 0;
      var selected = [];

      // Calculate days between
      if (d2 >= d1) {

        diff = d2 - d1;
        selected = Array.from(new Array(diff + 1), (x, i) => i + d1);
        
      } else {

        diff = d1 - d2;
        selected = Array.from(new Array(diff + 1), (x, i) => i + d2);
      }

      // Add selected class to each selected day
      selected.forEach(function(day) {
        $('[data-day="' + day + '"]').addClass('selected');
      });

      // Reset flag
      selectStarted = false;
    }

  });

});
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

td.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}

td.weekend {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<table border="3" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td>Mon</td>
    <td>Tue</td>
    <td>Wed</td>
    <td>Thu</td>
    <td>Fri</td>
    <td>Sat</td>
    <td>Sun</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day"></td>
    <td class="day"></td>
    <td class="day"></td>
    <td class="day"></td>
    <td class="day"></td>
    <td class="day"></td>
    <td class="day weekend" data-day="1">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day" data-day="2">2</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="3">3</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="4">4</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="5">5</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="6">6</td>
    <td class="day weekend" data-day="7">7</td>
    <td class="day weekend" data-day="8">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day" data-day="9">9</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="10">10</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="11">11</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="12">12</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="13">13</td>
    <td class="day weekend" data-day="14">14</td>
    <td class="day weekend" data-day="15">15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day" data-day="16">16</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="17">17</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="18">18</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="19">19</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="20">20</td>
    <td class="day weekend" data-day="21">21</td>
    <td class="day weekend" data-day="22">22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day" data-day="23">23</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="24">24</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="25">25</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="26">26</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="27">27</td>
    <td class="day weekend" data-day="28">28</td>
    <td class="day weekend" data-day="29">29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="day" data-day="30">30</td>
    <td class="day" data-day="31">31</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You could prevent adding/changing the classes to weekend days by using something like: `$('[data-day="' + day + '"]:not(.weekend)')`.addClass('selected')`

Comment: Thanks, that works very well. I may post my own solutio later as well. Thanks for the nudges.